# Jenkins Gerrit Trigger with parameters

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

We use Jenkins with Gerrit to trigger certain jobs on Jenkins. We use `Trigger on` `Comment Added Contains Regular Expression` to run the job. The job executes a shell script using maven `mvnw` command with some command line parameters for maven execution.

One of these jobs has regex like `.*(\+WEB_TEST|\+WT).*`. So whenever we want web tests to run, we put comment like `+WT` on the gerrit patch-set. Now we want to pass an **optional** parameter to maven through this comment.

Is it possible altogether?

Answer (score 0):

I think so... in the job, take a look at the $GERRIT_EVENT_COMMENT_TEXT variable. This variable contains the comments that triggered the job. Your shell script could use the variable contents to add (or not) parameters to the Maven.

See also at: **Build pull down menu** > **Parameters**

Comment: According to the [source code comment](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gerrit-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sonyericsson/hudson/plugins/gerrit/trigger/hudsontrigger/GerritTriggerParameters.java), this variable means `Comment posted to Gerrit in a comment-added event.`. However, it just outputs a hash of random letters and numbers for me. So your answer should be correct! I suspect I'm experiencing a bug...